Showing that a family of functions has size $\mathfrak{c}$
Let A be a matrix such that $A^i_k\subseteq[0,1]$ are sets with:$A^i_k\cap A^i_{k'}=\emptyset\Leftarrow k\neq k'$, $\bigcup_{k\in\omega} A^i_k=[0,1]$ and for every sequnce $(k_i)_{i\in\omega}$ the set $\bigcap_{i\in\omega}(\bigcup_{k\leq{k_i}}A^i_k)$ is at most countable.
Question: Show that there are $\mathfrak{c}$ many $f\in \hspace{1mm}^\omega\omega$ s.t. $\bigcap_{i\in\omega} A^i_{f(i)}\neq \emptyset $.
I think my approaches were flawed in many ways. I still wanted to post the most promising one:
I wanted to start building a binary tree where the vertices correspond to sets in the rows of the matrix such that, moving down any branch, the intersection of the sets is not empty. Then I can encode $\mathfrak{c}$ many functions using binary respresentaion ($b(x)(i)$) such that a $0$ corresponds to taking the left path ($k^i_l$) and a $1$ to taking the right path ($k^i_d$):
$$f_x(i):=\begin{cases}k^i_d, & b(x)(i)=1 \\ k^i_l, & b(x)(i)=0  \end{cases}$$
As for the tree:
Step 1: I start with an uncountable $A^0_k$. This must exist since I can't cover $[0,1]$ with countably many countable sets. I divide $A^0_k$ into two sets of size $|A^0_k|$: $V^0_1$ and $V^0_2$.
Step n+1: I find a set $A^{n+1}_{k_1}$ that has uncountable intersection with $V^n_1$. This must exist by the same argument as above. I split it into two sets of size $|A^{n+1}_{k_1}|$: $V^{n+1}_1$ and $V^{n+1}_2$. For the other $V^n_i$ respectively.
There are a few problems with this:

The sets in a row are only disjoint "up to being identical" and I need $\omega$ many different branches at each vertex since otherwise I can't encode all real numbers [SOLVED]
Doesn't this imply the set $\bigcap_{i\in\omega}A^i_{k_i}$ (or the intersection over any branch) is uncountable.  But the thrid condition would imply that such intersections have to be countable. [SOLVED]
(new) The intersection might be empty along too many branches.

I think there might be a much easier approach that I am too stupid to see, since all the other exercises from that chapter were way easier.

The first problem you identified, you are correct. If there aren't $\omega$ many different splits, there would be at most finitely many. That would imply that the $A^0$ would only get cut in half finitely many times, that in turn would indeed produce an uncountable intersection and violate the "3rd condition".
The second problem is not a problem at all, since "3rd condition" forbids sets to be uncountable.
There is however another problem. The intersection might be empty, wich is exactly what we are trying to avoid.

Choose $f_x(i)=k \iff x \in A^i_k$ this is well defined and the "3rd condition" shows that there are indeed $\mathfrak{c}$ many.
